# get Distinct Values with Sorted Data

Tags: sorting, mongodb, distinct-values

I need a Query to get distinct keys with sorted on basis of score in Mongodb *1.6.5*

I have records Like

```
{key ="SAGAR"
score =16
note ="test1"
}

{key ="VARPE"
score =17
note ="test1"
}

{key ="SAGAR"
score =16
note ="test2"
}

{key ="VARPE"
score =17
note ="test2"
}
```

I need a query which sorts all records on score and returns me distinct key.....

Comment: So what would the desired results be if you ran this query on this set of data (always the best thing to show when asking query questions)

Comment: What programming language you use?

Comment: @SagarVarpe - your accepted answer is no longer feasible (seems aggregation framework is only way to do this now).  Perhaps consider changing your accepted answer?

Comment: In mongo v2.2+, you can do: `db.test.distinct("key").sort();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [distinct command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) in mongodb:

you can use distinct like this:

```
db.test.distinct({"key":true,"score":true,"note":true});
```

the same in relational database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key,score,note FROM test;
```

And than [sort result](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order) by adding following code:

```
.sort({score : 1}) // 1 = asc, -1 = desc
```

Total result will be like this:

```
 db.test.distinct({"key":true,"score":true,"note":true}).sort({score : 1});
```

Comment: Evidently this is no longer feasible (v3.8.0) - yields error that sort cannot be used with distinct. Can you confirm?

Comment: sort can not be used with distinct

Comment: There's a feature request active, please vote for it if you have the same issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130

Comment: I have MongoDB 3.0.7, and for 1 field it works well:
`db.collection.distinct("date").sort({date:1})`.

Comment: MongoDB 3.2.5 only wants a single string as argument to [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

Comment: Can confirm this works when passing 1 field, as [distinct](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) expects.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the aggregation framework to group by the element you want to be distinct (group makes it distinct).  So if you wish to sort on score then get distinct keys you could do the following - sort by score, group by key and add score as arrays of elements (already sorted):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $sort : { score : -1 } },
    { $group : {_id : "$key", scores : { $push : "$score" } } }
])
```

This will result in distinct keys along with an array of scores which are those scores contained in the documents with duplicate keys.  I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for and I know this is an old question but I thought this might help out someone else looking at it in the future - as an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: $push is the wrong operator for that purpose. Use $addToSet instead.

Comment: @user3072843 to my knowledge, $addToSet adds the items in a non-sorted order, whereas $push adds in the order that they arrive into the group, which is in this case the sorted order.

Comment: ```[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$rankingPoint",
    },
  },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
]

Answer (score 3):

Using mongo shell v3.6.23

you can sort the data along with distinct values by using

```
db.test.distinct("key").sort();
```

you cant specify for which field you want to sort the result nor you can define the order.

eg: you cant use
`.sort({key:value})` here

the reason is that here **sort()** here is not the mongosh sort which is defined on cursor.

the **distinct** query returns javascript's Array.prototype, so you can use all [instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods) on it