# MongoDB distinct function and alphabetical sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, distinct

I have a simple question on sorting results from the distinct command in mongodb.

I'm using Monk in my NodeJS app to get categories from my simple DB:

```
db.getCollection('citazioni').distinct('category')
```

But how can I apply a sorting function like I successfully do when I find documents with:

`collection.find({}, {sort: {'_id': -1}}`   ??

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [get Distinct Values with Sorted Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759437/get-distinct-values-with-sorted-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monk has support for the underlying node.js native driver [**`distinct()`**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct) method and its **[signature](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/commit/99c32889912e969ab9995b2739d8b64d42f8a3a8)** is

```
Collection.prototype.distinct = function (field, query, fn) { ... }
```

As you can see from that commit that it implements the distinct method of the node native driver collection type via the .col accessor on the selected collection object:

```
this.col.distinct(field, query, promise.fulfill);
```

Thus you can implement it together with the native JavaScript **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method as follows :

```
// Perform a distinct query against the category field
db.getCollection('citazioni').distinct('category', function(err, categories) {
    console.log(categories.sort());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate it:

```
db.getCollection('citazioni').distinct('category').sort({'_id': -1})
```

In a Node app with Mongoose:

```
collection.distinct('citazioni').sort({'_id': -1}).exec(function(e2, categories) { 
    ... etc ... 
}
```

Comment: What I'm getting is:TypeError: db.getCollection("citazioni").distinct("category").sort({_id:-1}) is not a function

Comment: What I pasted is the only code I'm running in my MongoDB shell. In Node.js (Express) I'm calling: "collection.distinct('category', function(e2, categories) { ... etc ... }"   but I still don't know how to sort there.

Comment: Dear Michele, I really appreciate the time you spent looking into my issue, but I'm accepting the answer from chridam since it solves completely my problem. Thanks!